# Home button needs to to close app (or alternative strategy)

Tags: android

Typically applications cannot be "restored to the last screen" without also performing initialization.

For example, my app holds a live connection to a server which is established on initialization. It also needs to check for preconditions (like internet connection available, etc).

So when a user presses Home on the app and then restores the app, I need to restablish the connection (may require user input) and reinitialize everything.

I would've thought terminating the app on Home was the way to go, but from what I read, it's "not".

Just how are apps supposed to reinitialize themselves when restored on the Android platform?

note: I cannot use NO_HISTORY flag as it breaks the Google Play API.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the connections in the onStart method, and finish them in the onStop method, whenever the app loads up (new load of reloading) the onStart method will be called.

See the graphic [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html) for more details about an activities lifecycle

Comment: I have a dozen or so activities, am I expected to do this on every activity?

Comment: What I usually do if I have to do repeated things I make a BaseActivity and extend from that, then in the do things what will happen on every page. So in this case make a BaseActivity and just override the onStop and onStart, then each Activity what needs these connections just extends from the BaseActivity. I don't know if that would be any good for your case though, but that's how I personally handle these types of things.

Comment: How can i tell the difference between being stoppped/started because user "backed" into the activity or reopened the app?

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean. onStop is called whenever the app is closed (killed or just hidden), and onStart is called whenever it's opened (relaunch from the beginning or brought back from the background)